# Editar el contenido de los media min-width con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.
.
.
}
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de manipular el contenido de los media por medio de javascript o jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipular no, lo que puedes usar media queries en JavaScript por medio de [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) para realizar algo adicional a lo que tienes en la hoja de estilos.

```
if (matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
  // hacer algo
}
```

Respecto al soporte, tiene uno bastante bueno (ver el enlace).